# Is there a way to store the HTML pages generated by getServerSideProps on the server on first request and serve the same file for subsequent requests?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

What `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` do is generate and store files on the server at build time and serve it on request. Let's say I have tens of thousands of products so creating all those files at build time would be impractical.

Is there a way to store or cache the HTML pages generated by getServerSideProps on the server on the first request and serve the same file from upcoming requests and maybe expire after a certain period of time?

I found this example in NextJS's website. Is this the solution I am looking for?

> https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production

```
// This value is considered fresh for ten seconds (s-maxage=10).
// If a request is repeated within the next 10 seconds, the previously
// cached value will still be fresh. If the request is repeated before 59 seconds,
// the cached value will be stale but still render (stale-while-revalidate=59).
//
// In the background, a revalidation request will be made to populate the cache
// with a fresh value. If you refresh the page, you will see the new value.

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  res.setHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59'
  )

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

Is there anything else I need to know? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think the fallback option in the getStaticPath method is maybe the choice for you.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required

Basically it allows you to fetch pages, that you do not already have local from your build, on runtime from your CMS and stores the rendered HTML like in the build.

> If fallback is true, then the behavior of getStaticProps changes:
> The paths returned from getStaticPaths will be rendered to HTML at build time by getStaticProps.

> The paths that have not been generated at build time will not result in a 404 page. Instead, Next.js will serve a “fallback” version of the page on the first request to such a path (see “Fallback pages” below for details).
> In the background, Next.js will statically generate the requested path HTML and JSON. This includes running getStaticProps.
> When that’s done, the browser receives the JSON for the generated path. This will be used to automatically render the page with the required props. From the user’s perspective, the page will be swapped from the fallback page to the full page.
> At the same time, Next.js adds this path to the list of pre-rendered pages. Subsequent requests to the same path will serve the generated page, like other pages pre-rendered at build time.